# Unable to set user_version in SQLite

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

I am trying to use the user_version feature of an SQLite database. I am unable to actually set the user_version and I am not sure why. I have tried various ways of executing a query to update the user_version, and have searched extensively online and am now at a total loss.

Here is my query string.

```
const std::string kSetUserVersion = "PRAGMA user_version = 1;";
```

And here is where I am trying to set the user_version, however my result is still 0.

```
 // Set the user version and check it is correct.
 sqlite3_exec(dbConnection->db_handle, kSetUserVersion.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr, &db_err);   // <-- this is not working!
 long currentVersion = sqlite3_exec(dbConnection->db_handle, kGetUserVersion.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr, &db_err);

 // If the PRAGMA statement fails, no error returns and it fails silently, so having to add check to see if it has worked.
 if (currentVersion != 1)   // Setting the user_version has failed.
 {
    throw DatabaseAccessException(sqlite3_errmsg(dbConnection->db_handle));
 }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The [`sqlite3_exec`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) function doesn't return the result of your query, you have to use a callback to get the returned result data.

Comment: Do you want to set `user_version` or to query it?

Comment: Both. In this situation ideally all I want to do is set it, however I am currently also querying it to see if I have been successful in setting it. I will eventually need to query it elsewhere though to check if an update to the database is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sqlite3_exec()` return value is a status/error code and not the value from your query.

To get the query result value, there are two primary options:

1. Use `sqlite3_prepare_v2()`, `sqlite_step()` for `SQLITE_ROW` and access the data with e.g. `sqlite3_column_int()`, finalizing the prepared query with `sqlite3_finalize()`.
2. Supply a callback function as the third argument to your `sqlite3_exec()` to capture the value. See e.g. here for example: [Proper use of callback function of sqlite3 in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437433/proper-use-of-callback-function-of-sqlite3-in-c)

Comment: Thanks for your help. This seems so obvious now! However, I am unfamiliar with how to use a callback to return the user_version?

Comment: For future reference, the user_version only worked when set before any tables were created or changes made to the database. Thanks for your help.