# c++ sqlite3_prepare_v2 is not working

Tags: c++, dll, sqlite

This is my first post so excuse me if I forget to add some information, or my English mistakes.

I am working in c++ with code:block(13.12) making a DLL of sqlite3 functions and using MinGW toolchain. (windows 7)

I was using the `sqlite3_exec` function but I want to change to `sqlite3_prepare_v2`, `sqlite_bind`, `sqlite3_step`, etc because I think it will be easy to get back the return params.
However, after calling that new function from another program written also in c++, it crash giving me this error:

```
   Nombre del evento de problema:   APPCRASH
   Nombre de la aplicación: SQL_try.exe
   Versión de la aplicación:    0.0.0.0
   Marca de tiempo de la aplicación:    5594a5af
   Nombre del módulo con errores:   sqlite3.dll
   Versión del módulo con errores:  3.8.10.2
   Marca de tiempo del módulo con errores:  555cd28a
   Código de excepción: c0000005
   Desplazamiento de excepción: 0001ee21
   Versión del sistema operativo:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
   Id. de configuración regional:   3082
   Información adicional 1: 0a9e
   Información adicional 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789`
   Información adicional 3: 0a9e
   Información adicional 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I can not easily depurated it because I am not use to code:block and also I am calling the function from a DLL.

This is the function I am using, that i get it from this other post:[[Proper use of callback function of sqlite3 in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437433/proper-use-of-callback-function-of-sqlite3-in-c][1])

```
string DLL_EXPORT readFromDB(sqlite3* db, int id)
{   string result;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
     const char *sql="SELECT name FROM datos WHERE id = ?";
    int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql,-1 , &stmt, NULL);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
        return string(sqlite3_errmsg(db));

    rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, id);    // Using parameters ("?") is not
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {                 // really necessary, but recommended
        string errmsg(sqlite3_errmsg(db)); // (especially for strings) to avoid
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);            // formatting problems and SQL
        return errmsg;                      // injection attacks.
    }

    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    if (rc != SQLITE_ROW && rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
        string errmsg(sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        return errmsg;
    }
    if (rc == SQLITE_DONE) {
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        return string("customer not found");
    }

    result= string((char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0))+ " ";
   // *result=*result + string((char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1)) +" ";
    //*result=*result + string((char*)sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 2));

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
   return result;
}
```

I am calling the DLL function with:

```
typedef string (*Myfunc5) (sqlite3*,int);
Myfunc5 mifunc5(0);
string String;
mifunc5=(Myfunc5)GetProcAddress(  histDLL,"readFromDB");
String=(mifunc5)(db,1);
```

An I don't think that the problem is that the db is not loaded, because the other functions works and I tried to comment all except the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` and `sqlite3_finalize` functions, neither works.

Edited:

DLLSQL.h:

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>      // std::invalid_argument

/*  To use this exported function of dll, include this header
 *  in your project.
 */


    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
    using std::string;
    using std::exception;


            #ifdef __cplusplus
        extern "C"
        {
        #endif


        //void DLL_EXPORT SomeFunction(const LPCSTR sometext);





               int DLL_EXPORT CreateDatabase(sqlite3** db,string dbname);
               int DLL_EXPORT ejemplo(char db_err);
               int DLL_EXPORT CreateTable(sqlite3* db, string tbname,char * db_err);
               int DLL_EXPORT fill(sqlite3* db, string tbname);
              void DLL_EXPORT display(sqlite3* db, string tbname);
              void DLL_EXPORT jokersql(sqlite3* db, string sql);
              int DLL_EXPORT row(sqlite3* db, string tbname,string col,string id,int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**),void *answer, char **argv);
              int DLL_EXPORT n_row(sqlite3* db, string tbname,int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**),void *answer);
                string DLL_EXPORT readFromDB(sqlite3* db, int id);


        #ifdef __cplusplus
        }
        #endif
```

Comment: Your code worked for me as a normal executable, maybe it has something to do with how you are calling it in a dynamically loaded DLL. Are you linking with sqlite as a DLL or as a .lib?

Comment: I m linking it as a DLL, sqlite3.dll.

Comment: Another thing to check is that you are linking with the standard runtime library as DLL as well, otherwise you might have trouble passing std::strings between DLLs. Not sure how to do that in code blocks. Otherwise, put trace messages in your code if you can't debug it, to see where it it going wrong.

Comment: Show the exact definitions of `DLL_EXPORT` and `Myfunc5`.

Comment: Show the exact definition of `DLL_EXPORT`.