# SQLite callback function as class member

Tags: c++, sqlite

I’m trying to make the SQLite callback function part of my class. Any examples? I have tried this but it isn't compiling:

```
class Customer
{
    ...
public:
    int callback(void* data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName);
};

std::string Customer::getCustomer()
{
    ...
    int res = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlStatement.c_str(), callback, nullptr, &errMessage);
    ...
}
```

The problem is with `callback` parameter in `sqlite3_exec`.

Comment: You can check this link. May be it will help you.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437433/proper-use-of-callback-function-of-sqlite3-in-c

Comment: If it is not compiling, please add the error message of the compiler. This usually makes it easier to track down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use static method for `sqlite3_exec` as a callback.

define:
`static int callback(void* data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName);`

call:
`int res = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlStatement.c_str(), Customer::callback, nullptr, &errMessage);`